# (AWS EC2)phpMyAdmin : How to allow access from a remote user?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I made an EC2 instance and installed LAMP on it.
I can access (dnsAddress)/phpmyadmin from local host
but 403 forbidden error occurs when I try to access from a remote host.
I only followed amazon's manual which asked me to do this :

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/127.0.0.1/your_ip_address/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

but it seems that it only allows access from local host.
how can I allow access from a remote host? thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you reload Apache after editing the .conf file?

Comment: @user2182349 yes I did. is that command supposed allow access from a remote user not only from a local host?

Comment: You did change **your_ip_address** to your IP address right?

Comment: @user2182349 yeah, I'm sure I did it right because unless I typed that command, I couldn't access phpmyadmin even from a local host. so what I'm doubting is that that command above only allows access from local hosts, not from remote users. am I wrong?

Comment: Can you post the phpMyAdmin.conf contents (without your IP address)?

Comment: @user2182349 I'm sorry but that file is messed up while I was trying to fix something. but It didn't work before I edited that file. but as far as I know, It should allow remote users without editing that file.

Comment: Try to reinstall it. Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: just open that port in security group and make tcp rule to accessible to everyone